# Не получается вызвать компонент AngularJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, angular

Не получается вызвать компонент в AngularJS 1.6.

Что только я уже не перепробовал.

Создаю проект с помощью `ng new mcdates`
Потом `npm install`
Затем `npm init` ввожу называние проекта, автора и т.п.
Создаю компонент с помощью `ng g c mc-dates`

В папке mc-dates создаютсяя 4 файла. Вот код в файле mc-dates.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mc-dates',
  templateUrl: './mc-dates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mc-dates.component.css']
})
export class McDatesComponent {
  message = 'it works';
}
```

mc-dates.component.html:

```
<p>
  mc-dates status: {{ message }}
</p>
```

index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mcdates</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
1 + 2 = {{ 1+2 }}
<app-root>Loading...</app-root> <!-- вызывается -->
<app-mc-dates>Loading...</app-mc-dates> <!-- не вызывается -->
</body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { McDatesComponent } from './mc-dates/mc-dates.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    McDatesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Как видите ng сам создал необходимые файлы и прписал назввания класса в декларациях. Ошибок в консоли нет. Но при этом не вызывается компонент, что только я не пробовал. Знаю, что скорее всего решение очевидно, но я в силу малого опыта не могу его найти.

[image: Структура файлов проекта]

[image: Конечный результат]

Comment: Что-то тут не стыкуется. `@angular/core` - это никак не первый ангуляр. Да и тайпскрипт к нему хоть и прикручивается, но отнюдь не из коробки.

Comment: Хмм значит по cdn нужно второй подключать? Но ведь стандартный компонент работает <app-root> в index.html а компонент <app-mc-dates> не вызывается. В стандартном компоненте используется TypeScript, значит и в моём должен по идее.

Comment: Я и говорю, что-то не стыкуется. В первом ангуляре нет никакого стандартного `<app-root>`.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, у вас не `AngularJS 1.6`. У вас `Angular 2` или выше.

Во вторых, вы используете неверный селектор. При создании компонента вы указали селектор `mc-dates`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mc-dates',
  templateUrl: './mc-dates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mc-dates.component.css']
})
export class McDatesComponent {
  message = 'it works';
}
```

При использовании указываете селектор `app-mc-dates`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mcdates</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
1 + 2 = {{ 1+2 }}
<app-root>Loading...</app-root> <!-- вызывается -->
<app-mc-dates>Loading...</app-mc-dates> <!-- не вызывается -->
</body>
</html>
```

Используйте одинаковые селекторы `app-mc-dates` или `mc-dates`.

Согласно **styleguide** лучше использовать `app-mc-dates`.

Comment: Селектор поправил, но проблему не решило. Впрочем это и не важно, т.к. необходимо использовать AngularJS 1.6 а у меня видимо Angular 2 и выше, а там как я понял, по другому создаются компоненты. В любом случае - спасибо!

Comment: @ВоваСтрюков Интересно, как это могло не решить проблему... Очень интересно! Покажите код, который у вас получился.